# Laravel eloquent hasmany of hasmany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

manufacturers table

```
id | manufacturer_id
1  | 
2  | 1
3  | 1
```

parts table

```
id | manufacturer_id
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
```

Part model:

```
public function manufacturer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Manufacturer');
}
```

Manufacturer model:

```
public function manufacturer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Manufacturer', 'manufacturer_id');
}

public function parts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Part');
}
```

How do i make parts relation on manufacturer model to return part 1, part 2 and part 3 for manufacturer 1?

Comment: so, manufacturers has one manufacturer, parts  has one manufacturer and a manufacturer has many manufacturers and parts?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes

Comment: please, post all the tables with all the fields

Comment: can't understand database structure

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia each manufacturer can have many manufacturers and many parts, i need to get parts for manufacturer and its children manufacturers

Comment: so looking at your example, if you fave the manufacturer 1, with parts() you want to get the parts associated to manufacturers 2 and 3?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the manufacturer parts, you already have the right method, for the "child manufacturers" you have to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through like:

```php
public function childsParts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Parts', 'App\Manifacturer');
}
```

but probably you have to set the foreign keys and the primary keys in the hasManyThrough params

EDIT:
than you have to merge the two collection, like

```php
public function allParts(){
    return $this->parts->merge($this->childsParts);
}
```

The only problem of this, is that you are manipulating collection and not Builder, so after this, all the methods invoked on it, are just php scripts and not database query. 
If you want to paginate this, have a look at this https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Comment: this way i get parts for manufacturer 2 and manufacturer 3 only, but i need paginated result for all 3 manufacturers

Comment: yuo have only to merge the two collection, i'll edit the answer

Comment: as i understand merged collections can not be paginated

Comment: edited the answer in order to get a Builder as return, try and than tell me

Comment: actually this wont work, because union is part of the Query Builder, not Eloquent Builder... you need to user Query builder if you want the union of the two query without manipulating collections